# Rearrange the order of some HTML elements using JavaScript or jQuery (without having id to reference )

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

Is there a way to rearrange the order of some HTML elements using JavaScript or jQuery?

From this:

```html
<div class="link-wrap">
 <a href="#">001</a>
 <a href="#">002</a>
 <a href="#" class="move-this">003</a>
 <a href="#" class="move-this">004</a>
 <a href="#" class="move-this">005</a>
</div>
```

To looks like this:

```html
<div class="link-wrap">
 <a href="#" class="move-this">003</a>
 <a href="#" class="move-this">004</a>
 <a href="#" class="move-this">005</a>
 <a href="#">001</a>
 <a href="#">002</a>
</div>
```

That means whatever `<a>` with class `move-this` will be moved before others following their original order.

The challenge is that, there is no way to change the existing HTML code due to some limitations; not even to add classes or attributes to it. So, no idea how to do so after some research and testing yet.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: You can do this using CSS, if you make `.link-wrap` a `flexbox` container, then you can use `order` on the links.

Comment: @Andreas sometimes you spend a lot of time trying, searching, and researching, you are just not able to find a hint or the answer to it... And your suggested "duplicated question" is not the same thing and does not provide a solution.

Comment: That's not my dupe but I can live with it. I've voted to close this question as it needs more details ;)

Comment: @CBroe that's a great hint, I don't know it exists before, thanks!! yes, I can make it flex by custom CSS. Order property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#the_order_property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`prepend`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to move the desired elements to the beginning of the `.link-wrap` div:

```js
$('.link-wrap').prepend($('.link-wrap .move-this'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-wrap">
 <a href="#">001</a>
 <a href="#">002</a>
 <a href="#" class="move-this">003</a>
 <a href="#" class="move-this">004</a>
 <a href="#" class="move-this">005</a>
</div>
```